# Turn ArrayList<Integer> into one number?

Tags: java, arraylist, append

I am trying to figure out another way other than using `String.valueOf()` and then using `Integer.parseInt()`to turn an array of numbers into one type `long` number, not adding the values up, just like appending a String.

> Example: Let's say you have an `ArrayList<Integer>` of 5 elements and
>   the numbers are (e = element) ->
>
> e0(1), e1(4), e2(3), e3(6), e4(7)

So I want to turn this into one type `long` number -> 14367.

I need this to find a so called *Miraculous* number in java. I am to use lists, and print a miraculous number. (also any tips about that miraculous number?)

Comment: You could parse them as characters/strings. It's fairly easy and there are some threads on it here on SO

Comment: So that's the only way? Just sitting and playing around with parsing? No other way exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about this mathematically. What's the relationship between a series of digits and the number they collectively represent?

Each digit represents a power of ten. The last digit is the 10<sup>0</sup> place, the next is the 10<sup>1</sup> place, etc.

```
long number = 0;

for (int digit: digits) {
    number *= 10;
    number += digit;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh! How didn't I thought of that!? :P
I was thinking inside the programming box, forgetting about any other possible approach! :P
Thank you!

Comment: Won't `number *= 10;` give 0 all the time? Shouldn't it be `long number = 1;` ?

Comment: Wait, OK let's say an array is *6 2 3 4 5* so:
6 goes in, `number *= 10` fives 0 so `number += digit` gives 0 + 6 which is 6.. next 2.. comes in, 'number *= 10` which gives 60 since it changed to 6 last time.. so `number += digit` will give 60+2 which is 62.... oooooooohhhh I see what you did there!!! :D Perfect! Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest understanding doing this by hand. When we write 12345, what does each digit represent? For example, what does the 4 mean?

Comment: 1234 = 1000*1 + 100*2 + 10*3 + 1*4 :D

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski Exactly. You can use that place value of each digit in your `ArrayList` to convert it to a `long`.

Comment: @ZouZou Well, he was. But backwards :p And OP: That's 4321.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Yes I saw it was inversed. =)

Comment: Oh my god!! Hahahaha epic fail :D

Comment: So a java code for that would be something like that->
`for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){ long wholeNum+= list.get(i) * Math.pow(10, 10-i);}` ?

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski Compile and run that and what happens?

Comment: there are 10 elements

Answer (score 2):

This gets clever with the toString() representation of an array, but here goes:

```
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    String theNum = nums.toString().replaceAll("\\D","");
    Long.parseLong(theNum);
```